# WooCommerce Variable Product, how to get correct price of selected product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need a help to fix my code issue.

I'm try to add custom price with hooks `woocommerce_get_price_html`. The function is fine on a simple product. But when I tested with variable product and select the attribute, WooCommerce not give a correct price of selected attribute.

Here is my code:

```
function custom_single_price_html() {
global $woocommerce,$product, $post;
if ( $product->is_type('simple')) {
$reg_price = $product->get_regular_price();
//working fine for this condition
...
...
}

elseif ( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
$min_price = $product->get_variation_price('min', true);
$max_price = $product->get_variation_price('max', true);
$display_price_min_max = '<span class="sale-price">'.wc_price($min_price).' - '.wc_price($max_price). '</span>';

return $display_price_min_max;
}

else {
return;
}

}

add_action('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_single_price_html');
```

The code showing output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2h9O.png)

I want to show price range at the bottom of title and correct price of selected attribute at the bottom of select options.

I was spend out more than 4 hours to fix this bug, but still getting stuck.
Any help to fix this bug? Thanks